# "You can't take us points out for no reason"

Tags: meaning-in-context, verbs, phrasal-verbs

I was talking to my teaching assistant and I told him:

> You can't take us points out for no reason

with that I meant that my teaching assistant shouldn't lower us the vote of an assignment or homework without a valid reason. Is the sentence above correct? Is *take out* the correct verb for this context? If not or if there's a preferable one, which one is it?

Comment: In your sentence "us" is not the right pronoun.  Did you mean to use the possessive pronoun "our"?

Comment: @Andrew I meant "from us", if that makes more sense.

Comment: "Take away" or "penalize" are better choices.  But the more serious problem is that the syntax of your sentence is garbled.  Firstly, you can't usually separate a phrasal verb like *take out*; you would have to say "You can't take out..."  Also, *us* is not correct here, because points belonging to us are *our points*, not "us points".  Or you could reorder the whole sentence, so it's like "You can't take away points *from us*".

Comment: @stangdon Now that you mentioned these new verbs, they also sound better to me. Moreover, I asked this question also because I didn't like the structure of the sentence, it didn't feel so natural indeed.

Comment: Looks like you're adhering to German syntactical rules with your use of the pronoun ("... take us points out ..."). We do things differently in English.

Comment: "You can't take _usn's_ points out for no reason" is valid in some dialects, but I don't know (only because I haven't looked) whether this partakes of German-style syntax. I suspect not, though.

Comment: *Vote* is incorrect here. I think you mean *score* or *grade*.

Comment: @AlanCarmack Yes, right. When you speak more than one language the risk, absurdly, is that you end up not speaking not even one.

Comment: @nbro actually, you gain a new language, and you also can utilize *both* to express yourself (look up "code switching"), even if you make mistakes in the one you're learning (which is actually a sign of a good language learner).

Answer (score 3):

> You can't take points from us for no reason.
>
> You can't [take off points / take points off] for no reason
>
> You can't take our points for no reason.
>
> You can't [take away points / take points away] (from us) for no reason.
>
> You can't penalize us (by taking away points) for no reason

These are all valid variations on what you want to say.  There are probably more.

I don't think "out" is the most *natural* preposition to use with "take" in this context -- "off", or "away" are better -- but I get what you are trying to say.